# Comma before "than" [What better way to celebrate.., than...]

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, commas, comparisons

I'd really appreciate some help on this one.

Do I use comma in the following sentence?

> What better way to celebrate 30 years of *[name of my local football club]*, than with a win against *[name of our next opponent]*!

**Context:** We have a game coming up on the same day as we're celebrating 30 years and there would be no better way to celebrate it, than with a win against our rivals.

Thanks!

Comment: You can if you want. If you'd say it with a pause, then go ahead.

Comment: You don't need one for grammatical clarification, and there are people who say a comma shouldn't be used just to provide a breathing space (literal or metaphorical) in a long sentence.

Comment: If you're reading this out then you might want to have a comma to pace the sentence and build dramatic tension.

What better way...
(pause while crowd pays attention)
...to celebrate THIRTY YEARS of [club]...
(crowd cheers)
...than with a WIN...
(crowd cheers louder)
...against [RIVALS]!
(crowd goes wild)

I can't think of why else you'd want to insert a pause. You don't need one for clarity.

Comment: What better way to signal a pause than with a superfluous comma?

Answer (score 2):

English classes often teach the comma as a tool to be used whenever you need a verbal pause in a sentence; however, this leads to overuse of the comma, which I think is demonstrated by your sentence.

Let's simplify your sentence:

> What better way to celebrate 30 years of *[name of my local football club]*, than with a win against *[name of our next opponent]*!

becomes:

> What better way to celebrate Manchester, than with a win against Chelsea!

becomes:

> What better way to celebrate this, than to do that!

Once distilled, this sentence is ultimately a comparison between *a better way of celebrating this* and *doing that* (is there a better way? no), and thus should not contain a comma ([1](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma/)).

Answer (score 0):

Writers will sometimes put a comma before a conjunction as this is where speakers will naturally pause for emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: 
The comma does not make the sentence grammatically incorrect, but it is unnecessary. Too much of anything is not appealing.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. What reputable source is Me? I fear I have had the experience of  people, presumably under my instruction as to work, finding my words rolling off their head like a marble on a glass table. On those occasions, I would have liked a cure for that.

Answer (score 0):

The question of whether to include a comma before *than* in a sentence of the form "What better way to do X than with a Y" is ultimately a matter of stylistic preference and stylistic convention. Opposition to including the comma may be prescriptive ("Don't do that") or primarily descriptive ("This is how most people use commas"). Here is a look at these approaches.

---

***The prescriptive approach***

Prescriptive rules aren't so much arguments as dictates—and they can come across as remarkably arbitrary when presented without a rationale. The Grammarly page for "[Rules for Comma Usage](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma/)" that JeezLouise cites in a separate answer to this question favors the abrupt approach:

> **Comma Within a Comparison**
>
> Don’t use a comma before “than” when you’re making a comparison.
>
> **Incorrect** This box is lighter, than that box.
>
> **Correct** This box is lighter than that box.
>
> **Incorrect** Hardcover books are more expensive, than paperback books.
>
> **Correct** Hardcover books are more expensive than paperback books.

Well, there you have it: don't worry about why you shouldn't do it; just don't do it.

---

***The descriptive approach by exclusion***

A more complicated, roundabout, and exhaustive approach to the question involves checking whether this situation fits any of the main instances in which including a comma makes sense and/or is customary. Bryan Garner, [*Garner's Modern American Usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=l2LmCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA748&dq=%22First,+the+comma+separates+items%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi087H-vKbkAhXTop4KHYYnDNkQ6AEwAnoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22First%2C%20the%20comma%20separates%20items%22&f=false), fourth edition (2016), identifies nine appropriate uses of comma:

> First, the comma separates items (including the last from the next-to-last) in a list of more than two—e.g.: "The Joneses, the Smiths, and the Nelsons." ...
>
> Second, the comma separates coordinated main clauses—e.g.: "Cars will turn here[,] and coaches will go straight." ...
>
> Third, the comma separates most introductory matter from the main clause, often to prevent misunderstanding. The introductory matter may be a word {Moreover,}, a phrase {In the meantime,}, or a subordinate clause {If everything goes as planned,}. ...
>
> Fourth, the comma marks the beginning and end of a parenthetical word or phrase, an appositive, or or a nonrestrictive clause—e.g.: I am sure[,] however[,] that it will not happen."/"Fred[,] who is bald[,] complained of the cold." ...
>
> Fifth, the comma separates adjectives that each qualify a noun in the same way {a cautious[,] reserved person}. If you could use *and* between the adjectives, you'll need a comma—e.g.: "Is there to be one standard for the *old, repulsive* laws that preferred whites over blacks, and a *different, more forgiving* standard for new laws that give blacks special benefits in the name of historical redress?" ...
>
> Sixth, the comma separates a direct quotation from its attribution {"Honey, I'm home," Desi said}, but it is not used to separate quoted speech that is woven into the the syntax of the sentence: {TV loves catchphrases such as "Honey, I'm home."}
>
> Seventh, the comma separates a participial phrase, a verbless phrase, or a vocative—e.g.: "Having had breakfast[,] I went for a walk."/"The sermon over {or *being over*}, the congregation filed out."/""Fellow priests[,] the clergy must unite in reforming the system of electing bishops." ...
>
> Eighth, in informal letters, the comma marks the end of the salutation {Dear Mr. Crosthwaite[,]} {Dear Rebecca[,]} and the complimentary close {Very truly yours[,]} {Yours sincerely[,]}. ...
>
> Finally, the comma separates parts of an address {#8 Country Club Dr., Amherst, Massachusetts} or a date {March 2, 1998}.

To these nine uses, I would add a tenth—one that explains the comma after the word *blacks* in Garner's discussion of the fifth use of commas: Tenth, the comma signals omission of an implied word or phrase from a parallel construction—e.g.: "Is there to be one standard for the old, repulsive laws that preferred whites over blacks[,] and [is there to be] a different, more forgiving standard for new laws that give blacks special benefits in the name of historical redress?"

The sentence "What better way to celebrate 30 years of X, than with a win against Y!" doesn't fall into any of these ten categories of use. It doesn't involve a list of more than two items; it doesn't separate coordinated main clauses; it doesn't separate introductory matter from the main clause; it doesn't include a direct quotation; it doesn't involve a participial phrase, a verbless phrase [in the sense that Garner's "The sermon over,..." example does], or a vocative; it is unrelated to the salutation or close of an informal letter; there is no address to deal with; and there is no omission of a parallel phrase. Therefore—if Garner and I have correctly identified all of the categories where using a comma is appropriate—there is no need for a comma in the posted sentence.

---

***The syntactical logic approach***

Another way to argue against including a comma before than in the sentence "What better way to celebrate 30 years of [name of my local football club], than with a win against [name of our next opponent]!" is to look at the logic of the construction. Reduced to its bare bones, the sentence offers a comparison, and in this regard the function of the word *than* isn't any different from its function in these sentence:

> My local football club is better **than** its next opponent.
>
> I can't think of a better way to win a match **than** by repeatedly kicking the ball into the opponent's goal.
>
> What better way [is there] to sink **than** by not swimming?

In each of these sentences, both elements of the comparison must be accounted for in order for the statement to be meaningful; they aren't two freestanding ideas that happen to be linked by the word *than*. To the extent that adding a comma before *than* conceptually distances the two parts of the comparison from one another, it impedes the coherence of the underlying idea. To the extent that it merely provides a visual break after a string of unpunctuated words, it is a superfluous ornament.

---

***The real-world survey approach***

Matt3119, the person who posted this question, said that he preferred the sentence with the comma in place before *than*; presumably, then, he wanted to know whether his preference matched the broader stylistic convention (if one existed) for dealing with comparisons involving the word *than*. The answer to that question, I believe, is that convention generally opposes including a comma in such situations.

To test my expectation, I checked the first 100 Google Books search results for the sentence-opening phrase "What better way to" that also included an explicit *than* comparison (but excluding any instances where a parenthetical phrase set off with paired commas immediately preceded the *than*). In that sample, ninety-six of the sentences had no comma before *than* and four of them had a comma before *than* (although one of those four had a second "What better way to ... than ..." construction in the same paragraph that omitted the comma). A punctuation convention upheld by more than 90% of a randomly selected group of 100 published writers is, it seems to me, a fairly strong convention.

---

***Conclusion***

Whether to put a comma before *than* in a sentence of the general form "What better way to do X than with a Y" is a style issue. However, it is also the subject of a rather well-established convention of comma usage—and the convention is to omit the comma in such constructions. As is true of most other stylistic conventions, once you know what the "comma before *than*" convention is, you can reject it anyway (if your editors let you get with it); but in my view there is a crucial difference between refusing to defer to a convention you don't like and being unaware that the convention exists at all.